# Method not found: 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.get_GetMethod()'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, deployment, iis-7, web-config

I'm trying to deploy my project in IIS 7.0, I already did everything I know in IIS but still not working.

Here's the error message page.
[image: Error Page]

And here's my web config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProjectConnStr" connectionString="Data Source="";Initial Catalog=ProjectName;User ID=username;Password=password;Persist Security Info=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ActiveDirectory" value="" />
    <add key="smtpClient" value="" />
    <add key="smtpUsername" value="" />
    <add key="smtpPassword" value="" />
    <add key="smtpSender" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="9000" maxRequestLength="500000" />
    <authentication mode="None">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="30" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.cshtml" />
                <add value="Login.cshtml" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My project's **framework is 4.5** and I used **.Net Framework 4.0** in IIS Application Pool and the pipepline is **Integrated**.

I searched a lot of article but nothing's the same in my case. Please help, I already spent 2 days for this deployment.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Yeah2x, I already fixed this issue after 2 days, and I forgot how I did it, all I can remember is, there's a problem in my IIS setup, this is not in the web config issue.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem when deploying some new code to a new web server. It tured out that the web server did not have the correct version if ASP.NET installed. After upgrading to v4.5.1 all was fine.